# OptimisticConcurrencyException when deleting an ApplicationUser that has a parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I've extended ApplicationUser by adding a parent entity:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int MasterId { get; set; }
    public virtual Master Master { get; set; }
}

public class Master
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the related DbContext reference to the new entity

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Master> Masters { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I try to delete an ApplicationUser, `userManager.UpdateAsync()` throws an `OptimisticConcurrencyException`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        // Get the DbContext and UserManager out of the OWIN pipeline
        var db = GetDbContext(this);
        var userManager = GetUserManager(this);

        // Create a Master record if necessary
        if (db.Masters.Count() == 0) {
            db.Masters.Add(new Master { Name = "The Master" });
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        var masterId = (from m in db.Masters select m.Id).First();

        // Create a new ApplicationUser
        var user = new ApplicationUser {
            UserName = "Bob",
            Email = "abc@abc.com",
            MasterId = masterId
        };

        await userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password123?");
        await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        // Try to delete the ApplicationUser
        user = (from u in db.Users select u).First();
        await userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
        await userManager.UpdateAsync(user); // Throws OptimisticConcurrencyException

        return View();
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext GetDbContext(Controller controller)
    {
        return controller.HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
               .Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager GetUserManager(Controller controller)
    {
        return controller.HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
               .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
```

Just to reiterate, my data model has no concurrency-checking members.  The above code is cut-and-pasted from a newly created MVC app which I modified by adding a parent entity to the ApplicationUser entity.

Another note: In researching this issue, I ran across an SO post (which I can not find now) from several years ago that claimed that this is a known bug, to wit Identity gets confused when it tries to update the related records and sees that nothing (in the parent record) has changed.

And another note: I tried making the `MasterId` foreign key nullable, and set it to null before attempting to delete the user.  Didn't help.  The problem seems to be the presence of the foreign key in the `ApplicationUser` entity, whether or not the FK has a value.

Comment: Question: Why are you doing `UpdateAsync(user)` _after_ `DeleteAsync(user)`? In fact, why are you calling `Update` at all?

Comment: @ChrisCurtis Darned good question, no good answer.  For some reason, I got it into my head that `Delete(user)` worked like `context.Users.Remove(user)`, which doesn't get persisted to the database until you call `context.SaveChanges()`.  If you would be so kind as to post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: So this raises the obvious question: in what scenarios do I need to call `userManager.Update()`?  The "documentation" ("Updates a user.") is totally worthless.  Do all of the UserManager routines persist their changes?  If I modify the UserName or Email properties in my ApplicationUser entity, can I just call DbContext.SaveChanges() or does UserManager.Update do some other magic?  I guess all of this would be great fodder for a new SO question...

Comment: Yes, the UserManager handles all the persistence. You would use `.Update()` when you need to change a property value of the User. Just pretend you know nothing about the data layer and it'll be easier to use :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `UpdateAsync(user)` is not needed, and is probably causing your problem after the `DeleteAsync(user)` since the user has been deleted. Remove the update calls and you should be good

Comment: Was just doing as OP requested. I'll change it to be more answer like